# ng-show doesn't work with $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and can't understand why the ng-show in the below code isn't working.
The isLoggedIn is a variable in $scope.

```
<html ng-app"XYZ"
<body>
    <nav id="myNav" ng-show = "isLoggedIn" ng-controller="NavBarController as navCtrl">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse">
                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            </a>
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                <li>
                    <a href="sass.html">Sass</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="badges.html">Components</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>...</body></html>
```

Another template:

```
 <button class = "btn" ng-click = "loginCtrl.doLogin()">LOGIN</button>
```

The loginCtrl:

```
angular.module('XYZ')
.controller('LoginController', ['NetworkService',
    '$routeParams',
    '$location',
    '$scope',
    '$timeout',
    function(NetworkService, $routeParams, $location,$scope,$timeout) {
        var self = this;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
        // $scope.$apply();
        self.doLogin = function(){
            $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
]);
```

I tried calling $scope.$apply() after I changed the isLoggedIn variable which results in an exception '$apply already in progress'. I also tried encapsulating the doLogin's inner code in a $timeout() which also failed.

> EDIT:

config:

```
angular.module('XYZ')
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    console.log("Configuring routes");
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: "./templates/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController",
            controllerAs: "loginCtrl"
        })
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't put the solution in the question. Questions are for questions, answers are for answers. If you want to thank @Jorrex, accept his answer (there should be a checkmark next to his answer), and possibly upvote it too (via the up arrow next to the number). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are instantiating a new module, but it requires a second argument (the dependencies).

Since you aren't providing any dependencies, you actually do need to pass an empty array `[]` as a second parameter. And seeing you are using $routeProvider in your `.config()` you should have to include either the dependency provided by AngularJS or some other kind of "routing' dependency (such as `ui-router`)

So your code would have to look like this:

**Config**

---

```
angular.module('XYZ', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    console.log("Configuring routes");
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: "./templates/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController",
            controllerAs: "loginCtrl"
        })
    });
```

**LoginController**

---

```
angular.module('XYZ', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('LoginController', ['NetworkService',
    '$routeParams',
    '$location',
    '$scope',
    '$timeout',
    function(NetworkService, $routeParams, $location,$scope,$timeout) {
        var self = this;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
        // $scope.$apply();
        self.doLogin = function(){
            $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
]);
```

it's also a bad practice to reinstantiate your module each time, so assign it to a variable (`var myApp = angular.module('XYZ', ['ngRoute']);`) and use that variable to instantiate controllers, services, factories, etc.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/4tduu7z2/) to show the functionality (incl. the URL to angular-route.js, which you will need if you're using routing). It's not an exact replica of your code because JSFiddle doesn't handle routing all too well.

Comment: I took a look at your code and understood what the problem was you were facing. I edited your code and you can download it here, since I do not have a github account: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qakhat1hki19qat/Angular-sample.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hi. Yout modification works. Thanks for your help. But why do you think my code didn't work?

Comment: You were assigning a value to the scope of the logincontroller. The only real issue was that your $scope wasn't aware of the variable in your HTML. It's only aware of any variables in the template is is assigned to (e.g. Login.html) and since you used "isLoggedIn" in `index.html` it didn't know it existed. By using $rootScope, I assigned that value to the global $scope and by changing it with `$rootScope.isLoggedIn = true` in your LoginController, it was aware of that change and applied it to your HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

your controller is called LoginController therefore ng-controller=LoginController, the controller also needs to be called in the parent tag to any other directives....see below fix.

```
<body ng-controller="LoginController">
<nav id="myNav" ng-show = "isLoggedIn" >
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li>
                <a href="sass.html">Sass</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="badges.html">Components</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div ng-view>

</div>...</body></html>
```

Comment: unless he defined it in his routing, where as the `ng-controller´ is not needed anymore. But I guess this is the answer the OP is searching for :)

Comment: I actually defined it in the config as an alias. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('XYZ')
.controller('LoginController', ['$routeParams',
    '$location',
    '$scope',
    '$timeout',
    function($scope) {

    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;

    $scope.doLogin = function(){
        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
    };
}
]);
```

You need not a create a service for simply setting $scope of object to true or false, you can handle it using controller itself. And in HTML, do the following change for ng-click

```
 <button class = "btn" ng-click = "doLogin()">LOGIN</button>
```

This should work.

Comment: Oh, i missed to pass $scope as function parameter. I have edited my above code. Check now

Comment: You are welcome, please upvote my answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that the element I wanted to hide (or show) was out of LoginController's scope. Since $scope.isLoggedIn is being changed in the controller's scope, $scope is not aware of the HTML it needs to change which is not in the same scope. Putting 'isLoggedIn' in $rootScope works. Thanks to [@Jorrex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3287107/jorrex) for helping and giving me the solution and everyone who tried to help me.

```
//solution
app.controller('LoginController', ['NetworkService', '$routeParams',
'$location',
'$scope',
'$timeout',
'$rootScope',
function(NetworkService, $routeParams, $location,$scope,$timeout,$rootScope) {

        $scope.doLogin = function(){
            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
]);
```